# Auto-Double Application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create a quick program that will auto-Double the number that is entered in the text box.  
My issue is that nothing happens when I enter a number in the text box.
What I want to happen is take the number that is input in the text box and automatically have the number doubled in the adjacent text box.

**Question**
What do I need to alter in my code so that the double of the number entered automatically populates in the second text box?

**Code I tried**
**PHP/HTML**

```
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<div id="Form1" runat="server">
  <table id="table1" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="txt_number1" name="txtnumber1input" value="0" maxlength="10" size="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="txt_number1_doubled" name="txtnumber1doubled" value="0" maxlength="10" size="3" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="txt_number2" name="txtnumber2input" value="0" maxlength="10" size="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="txt_number2_doubled" name="txtnumber2doubled" value="0" maxlength="10" size="3" readonly>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
     function DoMath(el) {
   var id = el.attr("id").replace("txt_", "");
   var lbltext = document.getElementById($("#txt_" + id)).innerHTML*2;
   window.alert(lbltext);
 }
 $("#txt_number1, txt_number2").on("keyup", function() {
   DoMath($(this));
 });
```

Comment: and the question would be?

Comment: Can you use jQuery ?

Comment: @PedroLobito - yes I can use JQuery

Comment: @Dagon - what do I need to do in order to have the number doubled auto-populate in the second text box?

Comment: whats wrong with the js you already have.

Comment: @Dagon - the double is not being auto added to the second textbox

Comment: I've posted a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made some mistakes with selecting of elements

```
function DoMath(el) {
 id = el.attr('id')+"_doubled";
 $("#"+id).val(el.val()*2);
}

$("#txt_number1, #txt_number2").on("keyup", function() { DoMath($(this)); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery way:

```
 function DoMath(el) {
   // Fetch the value in the initial textbox
   var initial_value = el.val();
   // Find the id of the second textbox based on the first one
   var textboxname = el.attr('id') + '_doubled';
   //Do the maths and output it in the second textbox
   $('#' + textboxname).val(initial_value * 2);

 }
 $("#txt_number1, #txt_number2").on("keyup", function() {
   DoMath($(this));
 });
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ismaakeel/1y41pgLv/6/) for you to test:

Answer (score 0):

You said you could use jQuery, here's a solution:

```js
$('#txt_number1').change(function(e) {
  $('#txt_number2').val( $('#txt_number1').val()* 2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="txt_number1" name="txtnumber1input" value="0" maxlength="10" size="3">
<input type="number" id="txt_number2" name="txtnumber1input" value="0" maxlength="10" size="3">
```

Comment: autor want to write doubled value there - id="txt_number2_doubled"

Comment: I guess he can change the input id